# Invalid Projection error when using Geopandas

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

When I run the following code is causes `CRSError` as shown below:

```py
>>> locations = gpd.GeoDataFrame(Data,geometry = points)
>>> locations.crs = ('init','epsg4326')
CRSError: Invalid projection: init:epsg4326: (Internal Proj Error: 
proj_create: crs not found)
```

What does it mean and how i solve it ?

Comment: crs projections are usually referred to with a colon, e.g. `'epsg:4326'`. does that solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax `('init','epsg:4326')` is deprecated, and `epsg` needs a colon in any case. The following should work:

```py
locations = gpd.GeoDataFrame(Data, geometry=points)
locations.crs = 'epsg:4326'
```